# Date changes to 11 Feb 2016 and 1 Jan 2014 when I set the date before it and restart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, date, time

I want to set the date to "1990-??-??" on my PC, but when I reboot it, I see:

> On Ubuntu 1604 the system date is "11 Feb 2016" but the RTC is "1990-??-??".
>
> On Ubuntu 1404 both of them are "1 Jan 2014".

Is this Ubuntu bug?

I use the following commands to do that:

1. `# timedatectl set-ntp no` (stop automatic time update)
2. `# timedatectl set-time "1990-8-8 20:20:20"` (Set date)
3. `# hwclock --systohc` (sync RTC)

I test some dates and found that I could not set date before "11-Feb-2016" on Ubuntu 1604 and "1-Jan-1998" on Ubuntu 1404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `systemd` it sets the "reasonable" time when booting, i.e. advances the clock if it returns time older than the release date of systemd itself. These values are set in both [timesyncd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/ece6e766cf89c8ec82ad135969dedf16cd7c1ee8) and [init](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/021dd87bc055a5bfb2dcef83fc868fe24648b959).

This is the place that sets [TIME_EPOCH](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-commits/2014-May/006097.html).

Comment: Is it possible to change the date to any desired date?
If no, how I change this value or disable `systemd` to does not set new date?

Comment: You need to recompile `systemd`, either with the code I've linked to disabled, or with particular mtime set on `NEWS` file. No easy way without recompilation comes to my mind.

Answer (score -1):

On UNIX, there usually is a fallback with no working realtime clock:

The kernel then uses the time stamp from the super block of the root filesystem.

With the `date` command, you of course may set up any time in the range from  at least Jan 1 1970 to 2038

Comment: I use `date` command but the result was the same.
What do you mean " use from super block of the root filesystem" ?

Comment: If your `date` does not allow you to set the date to Jan 1 1970, it is broken. The kernel setz up the date by a value from the root filesystem in case there is no working hardware clock.

Comment: `date` and `hwclock --systohc` commands work properly. Problem occurs after reboot.